# Build Number Maven Plugin Repo Specification

Tags: maven

Using the [Build Number Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html), is it possible to get the buildNumber info from a *different* repo (separate from the one to which the pom.xml is associated?

I see that you can specify a local directory, using the [scmDirectory](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html#scmDirectory) paremeter. When using that approach, I get the build number from the repo associated with the specified directory. I'm looking instead for a way to specify the specific repo (in my case *subversion* repo) scm location itself, rather than a local directory on my file system.

I'm using the *svnjava* provider.

```
    <!-- Can i specify an scm location here instead of a local dir? -->
    <!-- OR if not, then a relative dir or scm location instead specific dir? -->
    <properties>
        <maven.buildNumber.scmDirectory>C:\\projects\\dir</maven.buildNumber.scmDirectory>
    </properties>
```

...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <revisionOnScmFailure>0.0.0.0</revisionOnScmFailure>
        <getRevisionOnlyOnce>true</getRevisionOnlyOnce>
        <providerImplementations><svn>javasvn</svn</providerImplementations>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible. Apart from that I would really ask why such thing is needed and what the purpose of such thing is?

Comment: Looking for a way to obtain the latest repo info (revision nbr, etc.) from a related repo during the maven build of a different repo.

Comment: You seemed to misunderstand my question: Why do you need the information from another repository in your project which itself is in a repository..? I understand that you like to get revision etc. but not why from another repository/project?